# Why in .Net C# does the Date format change after reading from MySql?

Tags: c#, .net, date

In MySql I have the date set as format yyyy-mm-dd on my PC and that is the format I see when I view the data in the MySql table. When I read the date and use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(tempActiveSince, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt", null).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Works perfect. But now have deployed it to a production machine and the date format in MySql hasn't changed but when I read from the database:

```
string tempActiveSince = reader["activesince"].ToString();
```

I get a date format error. When I print out the result of tempActiveSince I get the format of dd/mm/yyyy. I have ensured that the regional settings on the production machine are as per my pc but still not right.

Anyone have a direction on how I can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why read the date into a string? You should keep dates as Date (or DateTime) data types, and format on presentation (showing on-screen, in a report, etc.).

Comment: Dates do not have a format - they are just a numeric value - so it cannot change. Formats are simply how a date is displayed to humans so they can read it.  If you 'have the date set as yyyy-mm-dd in MySQL`, it sounds like you are storing a string, which is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: What exactly is the type of that "activesince" column? I hope it's not a varchar

Comment: Not a string the column is of type date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reader["activesince"]` is already a DateTime. You are calling  `ToString()` on it, which is dependent on CurrentCulture setting, which might vary across environments.

Two lessons here:

1. Read date like this: `(DateTime)reader["activesince"]`
2. When converting to string, always specify a culture, e. g. `reader["activesince"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 0):

```cs
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["activesince"].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string tempActiveSince = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```